# Ansible host "unreachable": true

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible, ansible-playbook

I just started learning the basics of Ansible. And facing some problem related to server connectivity via **SSH**. I created a folder named **publich_html** and put my code into that folder and changed the **permission**. When I try to execute my playbook it gives me the following error

> UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable"

Whereas when I try to **ping** servers from user home or root user without going into a directory it pings perfectly. Here is the **verbose** output :

> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d15 sftp -b - -C -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10

config file is:

```
[default]
host_key_checking = False
```

I don't know where I am missing something. Anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: With `ping` do you mean the regular unix command, or something in ansible? What does `ansible hostname -m raw -a id` show? I don't understand why you're mentioning the public_html (or is it really publich_html?).

Comment: with ping i meant ansible ping command. ans I am mentoning the public_html folder just because i simply created a directory with this name and put my playbook and role in it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently resolved a similar issue, where Ansible would encounter "UNREACHABLE!" errors only for tasks requiring file transfers (e.g. copy, template) while connecting just fine for anything else.  I resolved it by adding the following directive to ansible.cfg, under the [ssh_connection] section:

`scp_if_ssh = True`

As you might guess from that fix, the issue was related to the target servers' SFTP configuration.  Since Ansible uses SFTP by default to transfer files, the misconfigured servers encountered errors for any Ansible tasks that involved file transfers.  So, if this change makes the errors go away, I recommend checking your target servers' sshd_config files for errors in the SFTP configuration.

Comment: That's really awesome. And it will definitely help